# Renaming the current file in Vim

Tags: vim, vi

How should I rename my current file in Vim?

For example:

- I am editing `person.html_erb_spec.rb`
- I would like it renamed to `person.haml_spec.rb`
- I would like to continue editing `person.haml_spec.rb`

How would I go about doing this, elegantly?

Answer (score 91, accepted):

There's a [little plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1928) that lets you do this.

Comment: `code`:Rename %:p:h/_new_file_name.html.erb                          will save it in the same directory as the file being renamed.

Comment: :Rename <newfilename> will move a file from its location to the CWD, so make sure you set the CWD first or prefix the new filename with the proper subdirectory.

Comment: [This updated version of Rename.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2724) handles CWD correctly - always saves file in the directory of original one.

Comment: @sickill Here's an even better version IMO that tries to be smart, if the new file name contains a "/" it uses the full path, otherwise it assumes the current directory https://github.com/DelvarWorld/configs/blob/master/bundle/Rename/plugin/Rename.vim

Comment: @AndyRay The link is dead. Here is an updated link: https://github.com/DelvarWorld/configs/blob/master/.vim/bundle/Rename/plugin/Rename.vim

Comment: All of these versions fail if there are spaces in the directory that the file resides in and the directory is not explicitly specified.

Comment: @AaronMahan I've fixed Rename2.vim (disregarding the smarter but more complex DelvarWorld version) to allow for spaces in paths and forked it here: https://github.com/aehlke/vim-rename3 Feel free to submit pull requests for even smarter functionality!

Comment: Sourceforge is under maintenance so the link is gone. Please add at least the plugin name to the answer, so we can google around this.

Comment: @Stabledog Microsoft, apparently. `Program Files (x86)`. Any time this directory needs to be worked with it needs to be wrapped in quotes. Which is uh, a lot.

Comment: @JackHasaKeyboard: +10.  "Program Files (x86)" wins the all-time "Worst Ever Directory Name in an Operating System which Lacks Symlinks." :)

Comment: @JackHasaKeyboard, but who even uses that absurdly named directory?  I use `apps` myself.  Sure it's a pain to have to customize every install, but I feel it's worth it in the long run.

Answer (score 528):

The command is called `:saveas`, but unfortunately it will not delete your old file, you'll have to do that manually. see [`:help saveas`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/editing.html#:saveas) for more info.

**EDIT:**

Most vim installations have an integrated file explorer, which you can use for such operations. Try `:Explore` in command mode (I would actually map that to a function key, it's *very* handy). You can rename files with `R` or delete them with `D`, for example. But pressing `<F1>` in the explorer will give you a better overview.

Comment: Thx, Explore gets the job done, it is however a little awkward

Comment: :Explore works great! I'm getting rid of NERD-tree in favor of this!

Comment: I don’t think that it is awkward compared to other editors where you normally can’t move a file. Instead you have to go the file manager of your choice, rename the file, and go back to your editor. If you’re lucky you have to quit and restart your editor if it didn’t got the filename change notification.

Comment: @bzx: same here, I'm gonna map existing shortcut to open NerdTree to Explore :)

Comment: You might also like :Sex (shorthand for __split explore__ :-) )

Comment: Also, :e will open explore in the current pane. Less exciting than :Sex but more efficient ;).

Comment: For the intrepid, vertical :Sex is :Vex.

Comment: @bzx NERDTree does this, except you need to 'move': open NERDTree, `mm` then enter new name.

Comment: @Josh :E works for me, :e it does not work for me. I use :e to edit other file in the same window.

Comment: Whoops, I meant to put :e. (with the period at the end).

Comment: This is actually *the* solution in a scenario like this one: I want to create a new file `file`. I misspell the name on command line (`vim fule`), and I notice my mistake just before saving. Then, `:saveas file` is the easiest solution. This actually happened to me about five minutes ago.

Comment: Renaming in the explorer DOESN'T open the new named file in my open buffers! They still reference the old filename, which is not only awkward (You have to close the buffer and open a new one on the new filename)  but also dangerous (you could not notice, and continue saving changes to the old filename instead of the new.)

Comment: `:Sex` or `:Vex`, you'll need `CTRL + W` and then `Up/Down/Left/Right arrow key` to navigate between the `split windows`

Comment: One downside of `:saveas` is that it will lose the execute permission if you were editing a script. `netrw` Rename will keep the permissions.

Answer (score 213):

If you use git and already have the tpope's plugin [fugitive.vim](https://github.com/tpope/vim-fugitive) then simply:

```
:GRename newname
```

This will:

1. Rename your file on disk - in the same directory as the old file.
2. Rename the file in git repo.
3. Reload the file into the current buffer.
4. Preserve undo history.

If your file was not yet added to a git repo then first add it:

```
:Gwrite
```

If you'd like to move the file to a new location, use `:GMove`

```
:GMove path/to/newfile
```

Comment: I sacrificed two goats in honour of this answer! But I have a small problem with it, because you have to type the path from the root of the working tree; and this often gets rather lengthy in any project. Is there a solution to this?

Comment: @xxor: as mentioned in Mesco's answer, you can use Ctrl+R % to insert the current filename, which can then be edited.

Comment: To combine a few comments here: `:Gmove` requires the relative path for the new filename. A nice way to do this is to type `:Gmove <ctrl-r>%` which appends the current path/filename.

Comment: Doesn't work with new files that are not added to git yet.

Comment: @blues That is exactly why at the end of the answer it says: "If your file was not yet added to a git repo then first add it: :Gwrite"

Comment: `GRename` is the better option now. It renames the files and keeps the same relative directory

Answer (score 111):

I'm doing it with NERDTree plugin:

```
:NERDTreeFind
```

then press <kbd>m</kbd>

To rename you can choose `(m)ove the current node` and change file name. Also there are options like delete, copy, move, etc...

Comment: you know what, that is the main way I rename stuff these days

Comment: This one works really well. Definitely recommend it.

Comment: Love the idea. This will be my main change file name method now.

Answer (score 85):

- Write the file while editing - `:w newname` - to create a copy.
- Start editing the new copy - `:e#`.
- (Optionally) remove  the old copy - `:!rm oldname`.

On Windows, the optional 3rd step changes a little:

- (Optionally) remove old Windows copy - `:!del oldname`.

Comment: I use this approach all the time, however, the downside is that you lose your undo tree - so you can't undo anything before the :e

Comment: Nice.  Apparently Ctrl-6 does the same as :e#

Comment: you can also open the directory, move the cursor to the file and press "D" to delete a file.

Comment: The more straightforward way imho is 1) rename the current buffer `:f newname` 2) save it `:w` 3) (optionally) `!rm oldname`. The advantage is that your undo history is preserved.

Comment: This approach doesn't work with windows :). So I prefer no OS dependented solution.

Comment: `:saveas` is better in that regard, @rampion -- and does what @kynan wrote.

Comment: `vi` doesn't have `:saveas`, so `:f newname` is great, thanks!

Comment: What does the `#` represent in `:e#`?

Comment: @fstamour `:h alternate-file`

Comment: @orthocresol thanks!

Comment: I like this solution because it only uses `:w` and `:e` so is easier to remember

Answer (score 57):

### Short, secure, without plugin:

```
:sav new_name
:!rm <C-R>#  // or !del <C-R># for windows
```

<kbd>control</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>, <kbd>#</kbd> will instantly expand to an [alternate-file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5182852/in-vim-what-is-the-alternate-file) (previously edited path in current window) before pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>. That allows us to review what exactly we're going to delete.
Using pipe `|` in such a case is *not* secure, because if `sav` fails for any reason, `#` will still point to another place (or to nothing). That means `!rm #` or `delete(expand(#))` may delete completely different file!
So do it by hand carefully or use good script (they are mentioned in many answers here).

### Educational

...or try build a function/command/script yourself. Start from sth simple like:

```
command! -nargs=1 Rename saveas <args> | call delete(expand('#')) | bd #
```

after vimrc reload, just type `:Rename new_filename`.
What is the problem with this command?

*Security test 1:* What does`:Rename` without argument?

**Yes, it deletes file hidden in '#' !**

Solution: you can use eg. conditions or `try` statement like that:

```
command! -nargs=1 Rename try | saveas <args> | call delete(expand('#')) | bd # | endtry
```

*Security test 1:*
`:Rename` (without argument) will throw an error:

> E471: Argument required

*Security test 2:*
What if the name will be the same like previous one?

*Security test 3:*
What if the file will be in different location than your actual?

Fix it yourself.
For readability you can write it in this manner:

```
function! s:localscript_name(name):
  try
    execute 'saveas ' . a:name
    ...
  endtry
endfunction
command! -nargs=1 Rename call s:localscript_name(<f-args>)
```

---

*notes*

- `!rm #` is better than `!rm old_name` -> you don't need remember the old name
- `!rm <C-R>#` is better than `!rm #` when do it by hand -> you will see what you actually remove (safety reason)
- `!rm` is generally not very secure... `mv` to a trash location is better
- `call delete(expand('#'))` is better than shell command (OS agnostic) but longer to type and impossible to use <kbd>control</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>
- `try | code1 | code2 | tryend` -> when error occurs while code1, don't run code2
- `:sav` (or `:saveas`) is equivalent to `:f new_name | w` - see [file_f](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/editing.html#:file_f) - and preserves undo history
- `expand('%:p')` gives whole path of your location (`%`) or location of alternate file (`#`)

Answer (score 38):

You can also do it using netrw

The explore command opens up netrw in the directory of the open file

```
:E
```

Move the cursor over the file you want to rename:

```
R
```

Type in the new name, press enter, press y.

Comment: great! i did not even know about the netrw.

Answer (score 37):

**If the file is already saved:**

```
:!mv {file location} {new file location}
:e {new file location}
```

**Example:**

```
:!mv src/test/scala/myFile.scala src/test/scala/myNewFile.scala
:e src/test/scala/myNewFile.scala
```

**Permission Requirements:**

```
:!sudo mv src/test/scala/myFile.scala src/test/scala/myNewFile.scala
```

**Save As:**

```
:!mv {file location} {save_as file location}
:w
:e {save_as file location}
```

**For Windows** *Unverified*

```
:!move {file location} {new file location}
:e {new file location}
```

Comment: You could at least explain why you down voted this answer.

Comment: I didn't down vote, but this is not the fastest solution, though it's my fallback solution.

Answer (score 34):

I'd recommend `:Rename` from tpope's [eunuch](https://github.com/tpope/vim-eunuch) for this.

It also includes a bunch of other handy commands.

The Rename command is defined as follows therein currently (check the repo for any updates!):

```
command! -bar -nargs=1 -bang -complete=file Rename :
  \ let s:file = expand('%:p') |
  \ setlocal modified |
  \ keepalt saveas<bang> <args> |
  \ if s:file !=# expand('%:p') |
  \   call delete(s:file) |
  \ endif |
  \ unlet s:file
```

Answer (score 19):

For renaming existing file without using plugins you should use command

```
:Explore
```

This command allow you explore files in.directory, delete or rename them. than you should navigate to neccessary file in explorer than type `R` command which will allow you to rename file name

Answer (score 18):

```
sav person.haml_spec.rb | call delete(expand('#'))
```

Comment: nice! didn't know about `call delete(expand('#'))`

Answer (score 13):

```
:!mv % %:h/new_name
```

Register `%` contains the name of the current file.`'%:h'`shows the directory 'head' containing the current file, e.g.: `%:h`returns `/abc/def` when your file full path is `abc/def/my.txt`

Answer (score 11):

There’s a function in [Gary Bernhardt’s .vimrc](https://github.com/garybernhardt/dotfiles/blob/master/.vimrc) that handles this.

```
function! RenameFile()
let old_name = expand('%')
let new_name = input('New file name: ', expand('%'), 'file')
if new_name != '' && new_name != old_name
    exec ':saveas ' . new_name
    exec ':silent !rm ' . old_name
    redraw!
endif
endfunction
map <leader>n :call RenameFile()<cr>
```

Comment: Downvote me all you like. At least I can rename files.

Comment: This is a great answer, no extra plugin required.

Answer (score 8):

Vim does have a `rename` function, but unfortunately it does not retain the history.

The easiest OS agnostic way to rename a file without losing the history would be:

```
:saveas new_file_name
:call delete(expand('#:p'))
```

`expand('#:p')` returns the full path of the older file.

Use `:bd #` if you also want to delete the older file from the buffer list.

### Or create a plugin

If you want to use a quick command to rename the file, add a new file under ~/.vim/plugin with the following contents:

```
function! s:rename_file(new_file_path)
  execute 'saveas ' . a:new_file_path
  call delete(expand('#:p'))
  bd #
endfunction

command! -nargs=1 -complete=file Rename call <SID>rename_file(<f-args>)
```

The command `Rename` will help you to quickly rename a file.

Comment: :call delete('<C-r>#') 
is easier to write.

Answer (score 8):

There's a sightly larger plugin called [vim-eunuch](https://github.com/tpope/vim-eunuch) by Tim Pope that includes a rename function as well as some other goodies (delete, find, save all, chmod, sudo edit, ...).

To rename a file in vim-eunuch:

`:Move filename.ext`

Compared to rename.vim:

`:rename[!] filename.ext`

Saves a few keystrokes :)

Comment: And it indeed has some other very useful functions !

Answer (score 7):

How about this (improved by Jake's suggestion):

```
:exe "!mv % newfilename" | e newfilename
```

Comment: Hmmm, I should clarify that it worked on MacVim yesterday but I was sshed into a server and tried it today and the 2nd command didn't seem to be treated as a colon command...

Comment: Actually now it isn't working on MacVim either.  Back to the drawing board!  :)

Comment: It should be `:exe "!mv % newfilename" | e newfilename`

Comment: Thanks Jake, that's a bit better than my solution.  Updated.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if this is the "easiest" method, but assuming you've already saved your file (:w) I would invoke the shell (:sh) and do a simple cp foo foo.bak  To go back to editor use Ctrl-D/Exit.
Useful list of vi editor commands [on this link](http://kb.iu.edu/data/afdc.html)

Comment: This will copy the file, not rename it.

Comment: Ah - I misread "I would like to continue editing person.haml_spec.rb" My bad!

Comment: I suppose you could :! cp foo foo.new  and then :e foo.new ?

Answer (score 3):

You can also use :f followed by :w

Comment: This does not remove the old file.

Answer (score 3):

`:h rename()` is by far the easiest and cleanest method.
Just call it
`:call rename("oldname", "newnane")`

Answer (score 1):

This little script isn't perfect (the extra carriage-return you have to press) but it get's the job done.

```
function Rename()
  let new_file_name = input('New filename: ')
  let full_path_current_file = expand("%:p")
  let new_full_path = expand("%:p:h")."/".new_file_name
  bd    
  execute "!mv ".full_path_current_file." ".new_full_path
  execute "e ".new_full_path
endfunction                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 

command! Rename :call Rename()
nmap RN :Rename<CR>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to just use netrw, which is a native part of vim.

```
:e path/to/whatever/folder/
```

Then there are options to delete, rename, etc.

Here's a keymap to open netrw to the folder of the file you are editing:

```
map <leader>e :e <C-R>=expand("%:p:h") . '/'<CR><CR>
```

Answer (score 0):

`:sav newfile | !rm #`

Note that it does not remove the old file from the buffer list. If that's important to you, you can use the following instead:

`:sav newfile | bd# | !rm #`

Answer (score 0):

It's also possible to open a terminal from within vim with :terminal, then you can rename it from a terminal in an open buffer without technically leaving vim. It's not the same as issuing one succinct command but it is also a possibility.