# Can not switch to previous page in gvim

Tags: vim

I have a very weird problem which did not exist in my environment before but now happened. When editing files, I'm used to doing this way:

1. gvim . #open current directory browsing
2. scroll up/down to select file, enter then edit.
3. ctrl-6 #back to previous directory

However one day I found the step3 was failed, it said "No alternate file".
My .vimrc file only contains:

```
colorscheme darkblue

set number

set autoindent

set nowrap

set ignorecase

set cursorline
```

I tried to clean all content in .cshrc but the same.
Can anyone tell me what's wrong with my gvim ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Unrelated, but if you are a netrw user, make sure you check out tpope's Vinegar plugin: https://github.com/tpope/vim-vinegar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks to be a change in behavior introduced in Vim 7.4. The netrw view is no longer stored as an [alternate file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5182852/in-vim-what-is-the-alternate-file). See [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/vim_dev/lw3ywQzkI0k) discussion.

The Vim maintainers seemed split on what the correct behavior should be, but [Bram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bram_Moolenaar) himself [offered up this advice](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/vim_dev/lw3ywQzkI0k/mIl9KSvvi4QJ) with a mapping:

> I do realize that editing the directory of the current file is
>   something  I often do, but I never bothered to set up a mapping for
>   it.  Typing ":e  %:h" is not too difficult, but CTRL-O to jump back to
>   the netrw  %directory view was easier.
>
> I now added a mapping:
>
> ```
>     map ,d :e %:h<CR>
> ```
>
> Let's see if I can get used to that.

Another related discussion can be found [here](https://github.com/tpope/vim-vinegar/issues/25).

Answer (score 1):

You are likely using netrw to edit a directory. This is the equivalent of `:Explore`. Sadly netrw has a bad habit of not maintaining the alternative buffer, `#`. You maybe able to upgrade netrw or use `:Rexplore` (`:Rex` for short) to resume exploring.

Another option is to just use `:e` with wildcards and tab completion to explore files. Use `<c-d>` to list out completions as well.