# How to save a file with a new name in VIM while switching to that new buffer (and closing the original)

Tags: vim

The title about covers it: I know that

```
w! newFileName
```

will write to newFileName *while continuing to edit the original file*.

But I want to

1. write to the newFileName
2. Open that new newFileName in the current buffer
3. (Therefore meaning: close the original file without making updates to it)

Thanks.

Comment: You can do `:e newFileName` after saving to that file

Comment: true.. is there a single command?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Renaming the current file in Vim](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1205286/renaming-the-current-file-in-vim)

Comment: This is exactly the opposite of what is asked in [that question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4980168/vim-save-as-file-and-keep-working-on-original).

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The `sav` command should do what you want.

[Reference](https://vimhelp.org/editing.txt.html#%3Asav):

> ```
> :sav[eas][!] [++opt] {file}
> ```
>
> Save the current buffer under the name `{file}` and set the filename
> of the current buffer to `{file}`.
>
> The previous name is used for the alternate file name. The `[!]` is
> needed to overwrite an existing file. When `'filetype'` is empty
> filetype detection is done with the new name, before the file is
> written. When the write was successful `'readonly'` is reset.

Answer (score 6):

Another way of accomplishing this is to `:w newName` and then `CTRL-^` (which is the same as `CTRL-6`) to switch to the new name.

When you `:w` to a new name, it sets that as the "alternate" file name, and `CTRL-^` switches that to primary.  See `:help alternate` for more information on this.  Also useful is the `:f newName` which just renames the buffer (saving the old name as the alternate) without saving anything.

I like this a little better than the `:saveas` command because it doesn't introduce a new command, only a new shortcut, which is occasionally useful in other contexts as well.  It's always surprising to me that switching to the new name is not the default behavior of `:w newName` whenever I encounter it; it's hard for me to think of a use case where the existing behavior would be preferable.